# How to strip spaces and special characters during indexing with hibernate search / lucene

Tags: java, regex, lucene, indexing, hibernate-search

I have a field that I would like to treat as a single string, while stripping all non-alphanumeric characters from it.

For example, I would like to tokenize "123 456.78-9" as "123456789". In order to do that I have been attempting to define my own analyzer. According to the solr page the KeywordTokenizerFactory will treat a string as a single term and I can use a PatternReplaceFilterFactory to remove the characters as I intend.

I am using the following definition within my code and it is not working:

```
@AnalyzerDef(name = "strippinganalyzer",
    tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = KeywordTokenizerFactory.class),
    filters = {
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = PatternReplaceFilterFactory.class,
                    params = { 
                        @org.hibernate.search.annotations.Parameter(name = "pattern", value="([^a-zA-Z0-9])"),
                        @org.hibernate.search.annotations.Parameter(name="replacement", value=""),
                        @org.hibernate.search.annotations.Parameter(name="replace", value="all")
                    }
            )
    })
```

This matches "123*" but not "1234*" etc. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a custom Analyzer seems to do the trick:

```
public class AlphanumericAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

    @Override
    public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {

        return new TrimFilter(new PatternReplaceFilter(new LowerCaseFilter(new KeywordTokenizer(reader)), Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]"), "", true), true);
    }
}
```